# Serializing all derived types identically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a base abstract class for my data models (called `DataModel`) that contains a number of properties, including `ModelID` and `ModelCode`. There is also an interface with the same properties. I have dozens of derived classes. Those data models sometimes contain properties that are also data models.

How can I configure my `JsonSerializerOptions` so that anytime I'm serializing a class that is derived from `DataModel` it will write output `{"id":123,"code":"foobar"}` and nothing more? e.g. Even if a property on the serialize target is a datamodel I don't want to iterate over it (or any other property).

JsonConverters won't work unless I cast to IDataModel every time. I'm pretty sure the secret is in a modifier on the DefaultTypeInfoResolver, but the implementation escapes me. Any ideas?

Comment: Add `[JsonIgnore]` to all properties you want to ignore? Or use the non-generic JsonConverter? It has an `abstract bool CanConvert(Type)` that should allow you to handle any type you throw at it.

Comment: Adding JsonIgnore would be too much -- thousands of properties ultimately. But your point about the CanConvert is a good call; I can actually do that on `JsonConverter<DataModel>` and provide the specificity I want. Experimentation suggests this might be the best approach. I will confirm.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a custom `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` that checks whether the type being handled derives from `DataModel`. If so, then [customize the JSON contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) by removing the properties that are not declared on that `DataModel` base class.

This JSON contract customization takes place once per type that derives from `DataModel`.

```
public sealed class CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    private JsonTypeInfo? _dataModelJsonTypeInfo = null;

    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var typeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);

        if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DataModel)))
        {
            _dataModelJsonTypeInfo ??= base.GetTypeInfo(typeof(DataModel), options);
            
            var propertyInfos = typeInfo.Properties.Join(
                _dataModelJsonTypeInfo.Properties,
                derived => derived.Name,
                dataModel => dataModel.Name,
                (derived, dataModel) => derived
                );                
            var propertyInfosToRemove = typeInfo.Properties.Except(propertyInfos).ToList();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfosToRemove)
            {
                typeInfo.Properties.Remove(propertyInfo);
            }
        }

        return typeInfo;
    }
}
```

You set this `CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver` on the `JsonSerializerOptions` via

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = new CustomJsonTypeInfoResolver());
```

---

Alternatively, instead of inheriting from `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`, you can customize the `Modifiers` property of that default one to do the same as described above.

```
JsonTypeInfo? dataModelJsonTypeInfo = null;

builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()    
    {
        Modifiers = 
        {
            jsonTypeInfo =>
            {
                if (jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DataModel)))
                {
                    dataModelJsonTypeInfo ??= jsonTypeInfo.Options.GetTypeInfo(typeof(DataModel));

                    var propertyInfos = jsonTypeInfo.Properties.Join(
                        dataModelJsonTypeInfo.Properties,
                        derived => derived.Name,
                        dataModel => dataModel.Name,
                        (derived, dataModel) => derived
                        );
                    var propertyInfosToRemove = jsonTypeInfo.Properties.Except(propertyInfos).ToList();

                    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfosToRemove)
                    {
                        jsonTypeInfo.Properties.Remove(propertyInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: JonasH's comment above ended up being the way to go.  By overwriting `CanConvert` and then specifying any derived type, I could then create a JsonObject and write the specific properties to that.

Comment: @DuncanMack That might indeed also work, but your paying the cost for each item returned from your endpoint, whereas the JSON contract customization happens once per concrete type.

Comment: I see, fair. At this point I don't think the performance hit will matter, but I will keep that in mind and reevaluate if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on JonasH's suggestion, I ended up doing this which did the job:

```
public class DataModelJsonConverter : JsonConverter<IDataModel>
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options; // Options loaded here via a static call to another class
 
    static DataModelJsonConverter()
    {
        removeDataModelJsonConverterFromOptions();
    }

    private static void removeDataModelJsonConverterFromOptions()
    {
        var match = _options.Converters.Where(w => w.GetType() == typeof(DataModelJsonConverter)).SingleOrDefault();

        if (match != null)
            _options.Converters.Remove(match);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.Is(typeof(IDataModel));

    public override IDataModel Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return (IDataModel)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, _options);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IDataModel value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(value);

        var jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        addPropertyIfNotDefault(jsonObject, "id", value.ModelIDToLong());
        addPropertyIfNotDefault(jsonObject, "name", value.ModelName);
        addPropertyIfNotDefault(jsonObject, "code", value.ModelCode);
        addPropertyIfNotDefault(jsonObject, "state", value.ModelState);

        jsonObject.WriteTo(writer, options);
    }

    private void addPropertyIfNotDefault<T>(JsonObject jObject, string name, T value)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T)))
            return;

        jObject[name] = JsonValue.Create(value);
    }
}
```